# How to install mongoDB to MAMP with php 7.1.12

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp

I use a macos, mamp, and php7.1.12. I want an install MongoDB via brew, but I don't find a package for 7.1.12, I tried a package 7.1.but its doesn't work. Is it possible using this setup or not?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you need a MongoDB library for PHP? Do you have MongoDB installed already?

Comment: Yes mongodb i have installed, i can run in shell, but in php is doesnt possible. I dont know how to connect mongodb to php 7.1.12